# Restoring force in circular rod

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity

Can somebody explain how to calculate the restoring force in a uniform circular rod with known Young's modulus and diameter. I would need the restoring force in a specified distance from the origin with also a specified deviance.

Comment: Try this: http://www.bu.edu/moss/mechanics-of-materials-bending-normal-stress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force of a stress uniformly distributed over an area A is
$$
F = \sigma \times A
$$

Stress = Young's modulus * strain
$$
\sigma = E \times \epsilon
$$

Strain = displacement / Length
$$
\epsilon = {u \over L}
$$

so putting it together, along with the area of a circle:
$$
F = E \times {u \over L} \times \pi \times d^2/4
$$

That gives positive force for a positive displacement. If you want the restoring force applied to the thing that causes the displacement, negate it.

The force is the same at any distance along the bar.